# How can I transfer my results from GAMS to Python?

Tags: python, resultset, transfer, gams-math

I built my first GAMS code, but I don't know how to transfer the results from the lst file to Python in order to process. If anyone could help with the issue I would be very grateful. For example, for the transportation problem how can I transfer the total cost and the shipment quantities in a Python project?

$Title  A Transportation Problem (TRNSPORT,SEQ=1)
$Ontext

This problem finds a least cost shipping schedule that meets
requirements at markets and supplies at factories.

Dantzig, G B, Chapter 3.3. In Linear Programming and Extensions.
Princeton University Press, Princeton, New Jersey, 1963.

This formulation is described in detail in:
Rosenthal, R E, Chapter 2: A GAMS Tutorial. In GAMS: A User's Guide.
The Scientific Press, Redwood City, California, 1988.

The line numbers will not match those in the book because of these
comments.

$Offtext

Sets
i   canning plants   / seattle, san-diego /
j   markets          / new-york, chicago, topeka / ;

Parameters

```
   a(i)  capacity of plant i in cases
     /    seattle     350
          san-diego   600  /

   b(j)  demand at market j in cases
     /    new-york    325
          chicago     300
          topeka      275  / ;
```

Table d(i,j)  distance in thousands of miles
new-york       chicago      topeka
seattle          2.5           1.7          1.8
san-diego        2.5           1.8          1.4  ;

Scalar f  freight in dollars per case per thousand miles  /90/ ;

Parameter c(i,j)  transport cost in thousands of dollars per case ;

```
        c(i,j) = f * d(i,j) / 1000 ;
```

Variables
x(i,j)  shipment quantities in cases
z       total transportation costs in thousands of dollars ;

Positive Variable x ;

Equations
cost        define objective function
supply(i)   observe supply limit at plant i
demand(j)   satisfy demand at market j ;

cost ..        z  =e=  sum((i,j), c(i,j)*x(i,j)) ;

supply(i) ..   sum(j, x(i,j))  =l=  a(i) ;

demand(j) ..   sum(i, x(i,j))  =g=  b(j) ;

Model transport /all/ ;

Solve transport using lp minimizing z ;

Display x.l, x.m ;

Comment: There are many, many ways to do this. A first attempt can be to write a CSV file using PUT.